How to draw random curves with parts dotted and some solid in 3D
I am having trouble making some parts of my curves with dotted (assumed to be behind the plane) and extended under the plane. Also, I need to have two other coppies of those curves. The part that i cannot figure out is the dotted and solid lines portions would be different for the other two copies because they are located in different part of the plane.
This is what I want to add to my code (the red ink).

Here is my code
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d} 


\tikzset
{% styles
   axis/.style={thick,-latex},
   yz/.style={canvas is yz plane at x=0},
   xz/.style={canvas is xz plane at y=0},
   xz rotated/.style={rotate around z=\mytheta,xz},
   xy elevated/.style={canvas is xy plane at z={\myradius*cos(\myphi)},scale={sin(\myphi)}},
   sphere/.style={shading=ball,fill opacity=0.3},
   plane/.style={fill=teal,fill opacity=0.3},
   cone/.style={fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.3},
   vector/.style={very thick,-stealth},
   point/.style={shading=ball,ball color=red}
}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,arrows,through,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings, snakes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round, x={(-0.4cm,-0.4cm)}, y={(0.8cm,0)},z={(0,0.6cm)}]

    \coordinate (x1) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (x2) at (7,0,0);
    \coordinate (x3) at (7,9.5,0);
    \coordinate (x4) at (0,9.5,0);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%              
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (10,0,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,10,0) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) node[above] {$z$};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\draw [dotted, line width=0.7pt] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(0.25,1,-0.5)(0.15,1.5,-0.25) (0.2,3,-0.2) (0.3,4.5,-0.1)(0.4,6,-0.1)(1.5,7,-1)(4,7.5,-1.2)(4.5,5.5,-1.2)(5,2.5,0.2) }; %smooth contour

\draw[draw=black, fill=gray!50!white, nearly transparent,thick] (x1) -- (x2) -- (x3)-- (x4); %the gray plane
\draw[draw=black, line width=2pt] (x1) -- (x2) -- (x3)-- (x4)--(x1); %the gray plane
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw [black, line width=2pt] plot [smooth, tension=0.5] coordinates { (1,2,-2)(2,3,1)(3,4,3)(4,5.5,5)}; %line l_1
\draw [black, line width=2pt, xshift=3cm, yshift=0.9cm] plot [smooth, tension=0.5] coordinates { (1,2,-2)(2,3,1)(3,4,3)(4,5.5,5)}; %line 1_j
\draw [black, line width=2pt, xshift=1cm, yshift=-0.5cm] plot [smooth, tension=0.5] coordinates { (1,2,-2)(2,3,1)(3,4,3)(4,5.5,5)}; %line l_i
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw [black, line width=2pt] plot [smooth, tension=0.8] coordinates { (7,4.1,0)(7.5,4,-0.5)(8,4.1,-2)};
\draw [black, line width=2pt, xshift=3cm, yshift=0.9cm]plot [smooth, tension=0.9] coordinates { (7,4.1,0)(7.5,4,-0.5)(8,4.1,-2)};
\draw [black, line width=2pt, xshift=1cm, yshift=-0.5cm] plot [smooth, tension=0.8] coordinates { (7,4.1,0)(7.5,4,-0.5)(8,4.1,-2)};
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill (1,2,-2) circle[radius=1mm] ;
\fill (1,2,-2) circle[radius=1mm, xshift=3cm, yshift=0.9cm] ;
\fill (1,2,-2) circle[radius=1mm, xshift=1cm, yshift=-0.5cm] ;
%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \draw[]  (1,2,-2) node[left,xshift=-2pt] {$l_1$};
 \draw[]  (1,2,-2) node[left,xshift=3cm, yshift=0.9cm] {$l_i$};
  \draw[]  (1,2,-2) node[left,xshift=1cm, yshift=-0.5cm] {$l_j$};
  \draw[]  (4,5.5,5.5) node[left,xshift=3cm, yshift=0.9cm] {$q(z)$};
  
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} 


If the obscured lines under the plane don't need to be red or dashed, you can simply change the order of how things are drawn and use fill opacity to dim the lines when under the plane.

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d} 


\tikzset
{% styles
   axis/.style={thick,-latex},
   yz/.style={canvas is yz plane at x=0},
   xz/.style={canvas is xz plane at y=0},
   xz rotated/.style={rotate around z=\mytheta,xz},
   xy elevated/.style={canvas is xy plane at z={\myradius*cos(\myphi)},scale={sin(\myphi)}},
}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,arrows,through,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings, snakes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round, x={(-0.4cm,-0.4cm)}, y={(0.8cm,0)},z={(0,0.6cm)}]

    \coordinate (x1) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (x2) at (7,0,0);
    \coordinate (x3) at (7,9.5,0);
    \coordinate (x4) at (0,9.5,0);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%              
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (10,0,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,10,0) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) node[above] {$z$};
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}[black, line width=2pt]
    \foreach \x / \y in {0cm/0cm, 3cm/0.9cm, 1cm/-0.5cm }
    {
        \draw [xshift=\x, yshift=\y] plot [smooth, tension=0.8] coordinates { (7,4.1,0)(7.5,4,-0.5)(8,4.1,-2)};
        \draw [xshift=\x, yshift=\y] plot [smooth, tension = 0.5] coordinates { (1,2,-2)(5.0,3.9,0)(7,4.1,0)};
    }
    \filldraw[fill=gray!30!white,fill opacity=0.75] (x1) -- (x2) -- (x3)-- (x4) -- cycle; %the gray plane
    \foreach \x / \y in {0cm/0cm, 3cm/0.9cm, 1cm/-0.5cm }
    {
        \draw [xshift=\x, yshift=\y] plot [smooth, tension=0.5] coordinates { (1,2,-2)(2,3,1)(3,4,3)(4,5.5,5)}; %line l_1
        \fill (1,2,-2) circle[radius=1mm, xshift=\x, yshift=\y] ;
    }
\end{scope}

\draw [dotted, line width=0.7pt] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(0.25,1,-0.5)(0.15,1.5,-0.25) (0.2,3,-0.2) (0.3,4.5,-0.1)(0.4,6,-0.1)(1.5,7,-1)(4,7.5,-1.2)(4.5,5.5,-1.2)(5,2.5,0.2) }; %smooth contour

%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \draw[]  (1,2,-2) node[left,xshift=-2pt] {$l_1$};
 \draw[]  (1,2,-2) node[left,xshift=3cm, yshift=0.9cm] {$l_i$};
  \draw[]  (1,2,-2) node[left,xshift=1cm, yshift=-0.5cm] {$l_j$};
  \draw[]  (4,5.5,5.5) node[left,xshift=3cm, yshift=0.9cm] {$q(z)$};
  
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} 



Thank you! No I did not want it to be red. :)
